# How to concat arrays with differend fixed sizes?

Tags: arrays, rust

I'm trying Rust and unfortunately I'm already stuck with small tasks like concating `u8` arrays.

I am trying to join the following arrays:

```rust
let arrayOne: &[u8; 500] = &[0; 500];
let arrayTwo: &[u8; 100] = &[1; 100];
let arrayThree: &[u8] = &[1, 2, 3];

let mergedArray = [arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree].concat();
```

but im getting the error:

```
mismatched types
expected an array with a fixed size of 500 elements, found one with 100 elementsrustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
let arrayTwo: &[u8; 100] // size = 8, align = 0x8
```

I don't quite understand why this is not allowed and how it is otherwise done.

Especially since the following code seems to be ok:

```rust
let arrayOne: &[u8; 500] = &[0; 500];
let arrayThree: &[u8] = &[1, 2, 3];

let mergedArray = [arrayOne, arrayThree].concat();
```

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6d8624f3846d80a427cc7ae1eb67f562 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the first example is that once the compiler looks at the second item it tries to coerce the `&[u8; 500]` to a `&[u8; 100]` and vice versa, neither of which are allowed coercions. It doesn't see that both could be coerced to the same `&[u8]` because that would require checking all possible coercion targets every time wich would have a massive performance impact on compilation.

The second example works because once the type of the second element `&[u8]` is encounterd it sees it can coerce `&[u8; 500]` to a slice, too and is able to continue.

You can cast the first array reference to a slice to help the compiler figure out that everything should be coerced to slices:

```rust
fn main() {
    let array_one: &[u8; 500] = &[0; 500];
    let array_two: &[u8; 100] = &[0; 100];
    let array_three: &[u8] = &[1, 2, 3];

    let merged_array = [array_one as &[_], array_two, array_three].concat();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply :) maybe the compiler will get smarter in the future :D I will follow your solution

Comment: Or `&array_one[..]`, `array_one.as_slice()`.